# Cannot get Div to fill full width on Wordpress

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div that covers the whole width of the screen so that section of the screen is coloured.

This is on wordpress and I am not sure how to fill the whole area.
(Visit Us/Deal/Book Now part is not working the way I want it to)

*edit*
The CSS code is updated but it only goes to half of the page width

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

section {
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    width:100%;
}

.visit {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    display: flex;
    margin-left:-55px;
}

table {
    width:100%;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

tr {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border-width:0px;
    background-color:#15b6b8;
}

td {
    width:33%;
    height:30%;
}

td h4 {
    text-align:center;
}

input {
    text-align:center;
    width:80%;
}
```

```html
<code>
    <section class="1">
        <div class="description">
            <h3>Alicia's Laser Med Spa and Salon</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="visit">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h4>Visit Us</h4>
                        <!--map--></td>
                    <td>
                        <h4>Today's Deal</h4>
                        <!-- Deal Picture --></td>
                    <td>
                        <h4>Book Now</h4>
                        <form data-myki-checked-cc="3"><input name="qname" type="text"
                                                              placeholder="Name" />
                            <input name="qemail" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
                            <input name="qphone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" />
                        </form></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
</code>
```

This code [result](https://paste.pics/04c3037fa03d89571bc2394e34368adb)

Comment: This is how it ends up looking
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeqtd.jpg

Comment: It's because the the section seems to be inside a container.

Comment: yes as I see the body of the page (section after the nav) is inside of a container with some padding.

Comment: What is the plugin that you are using?

Comment: I didn't use any plugins yet

Comment: @KryticalMass Since you are not using any plugin, you need to arrange your DOM

Answer (score 0):

In this case your code is inside the `container` which is the bootstrap class. In order to achieve what you are looking for is you can have a `wrapper` outside the `container` and set the `background-color`.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  height:50px;
}
.container>div{
  background-color:yellow;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Your content -->
    <div>This is a sample Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does wordpress use boostrap?

Comment: It's not word press. It's your theme using bootstrap.To make sure *view page source* and check whether the bootstrap is included or not.

Comment: This is on wordpress

Comment: @KryticalMass I know, but you have a active theme in wordpress. The theme's `index.php` or `page.php` is loaded to normal pages. I think you are extremely new to wordpress. Learn about wordpress structure to understand the concept https://wpbeaches.com/how-to-find-out-what-wordpress-template-is-being-used-in-a-theme/

Answer (score 0):

You could position it `absolute` at the left border like that:

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

tr {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  background-color: #15b6b8;
}

td {
  width: 33%;
  height: 30%;
}

td h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<section class="1">
  <div class="description">
    <h3>Alicia's Laser Med Spa and Salon</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="visit">
    <table width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4>Visit Us</h4>
            <!--map-->
          </td>
          <td>
            <h4>Today's Deal</h4>
            <!-- Deal Picture -->
          </td>
          <td>
            <h4>Book Now</h4>
            <form data-myki-checked-cc="3"><input name="qname" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
              <input name="qemail" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
              <input name="qphone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" />
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This sort of worked but now I have this:
https://paste.pics/04c3037fa03d89571bc2394e34368adb

Comment: @KryticalMass do you still have `width: 100%`? If this doesn't work, you can try `right: 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
}

table {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

tr {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  background-color: #15b6b8;
}

td {
  width: 33%;
  height: 30%;
}

td h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}

.visit{
  width: 100% auto;
}

.fix-column{
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 2em auto;

}


<code>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="description">
      <h3>Alicia's Laser Med Spa and Salon</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="visit">
      <div class="fix-column">
      <table >
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h4>Visit Us</h4>
              <!--map-->
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4>Today's Deal</h4>
              <!-- Deal Picture -->
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4>Book Now</h4>
              <form data-myki-checked-cc="3">
                <input name="qname" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
                <input name="qemail" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
                <input name="qphone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" />
              </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</code>
```

Here is link for demo [full width text center demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhc9jg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without disturbing the document flow, you can use negative margin to reposition the element. What you need to find out is how much margin and/or padding is used for the parent(s). Below I use for the section: margin: 30px, padding: 10px.

As a result, the negative margin for the content is -40px.

The colors are used to improve visibility of the effect.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  margin: 0 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: -40px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.content>h2 {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Alicia's Laser Med Spa and Salon</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Visit Us</h2>
    <h2>Today's Deal</h2>
    <h2>Book Now</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `position:absolute` is not a good answer all the time. It make other elements feel the absolute element is not exist.